# Why using std::forward on container before accessing element?

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

Scott Meyers in his new book "Effective Modern C++" shows the following function as an example of using `decltype(auto)` (page 28):

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto) 
authAndAccess(Container&& c, Index i)
{
  authenticateUser();
  return std::forward<Container>(c)[i];
}
```

My question is simple. Why do we need `std::forward` applied to `c` here? We are not passing `c` anywhere, we are calling `operator[]` on it. And none of standard containers have ref-qualified overloads (r-value/l-value overloads) of `operator[]`.

So I see only two reasons for this `std::forward`:

1. To account for *potential* containers which implement ref-qualified overloads of `operator[]`.
2. For consistency: whenever a variable declared as forwarding (universal) reference is used, apply `std::forward` on it. Period.

Any other reasons?

Comment: The standard containers are allowed to overload operator[] on ref-qualification, and other containers might as well. I don't like 2. because it doesn't mention that you can only forward once.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of a container that might have a different ref-qualified implementation? Off the top of my head, I can't think of one. (That's not to imply anything about whether or not I think we should std::forward.)

Comment: @kec There are no such containers in the standard library, but it seems reasonable that a container that implements `operator[]` to return an lvalue-reference when called on an lvalue object may return an rvalue-reference or value when called on an rvalue object. `foo{}.bar` is an rvalue, why shouldn't `foo{}[37]` be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reason #1 is the relevant one. When you implement a generic function, you don't go by "What do these particular types I know about do?", but by "What do I know about the generic thing I am working with?".

The generic container doesn't say anything about reference qualification, so you forward.

Of course, reason #2 is much easier to remember and reason about, so you should follow that.

I don't think there are any other reasons.

Comment: The OP isn't asking whether the two reasonings are correct. It asks for more.

Comment: The OP sounded unconvinced by those reasons ("**only** two reasons", as if that's not plenty), so I tried to elaborate on them instead. If we always just answered the exact question asked, we would never get any useful results on this site.

Comment: You elaborated on them in four lines?

Comment: @Columbo elaborations are not always ... elaborate. Sometimes they're simple clarifications or redirections encouraging one to think about a thing in a slightly different manner...

Comment: Would please explain more? Because I have removed `std::forward` and just return `c[i]`. It works as before. I'm not c++ expert, so would you explain it in easy words?

Comment: Create a container that overloads `operator[]` on reference qualifiers, then pass an rvalue container to `authAndAccess`. You'll end up calling different `operator[]`s, depending on whether you use `std::forward` inside `authAndAccess`.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe But why would anyone want to create a container that has 2 versions of operator[]: one for lvalues and one for rvalues? Is there any reasonable use case that would utilize it? How would the rvalue version of operator[] differ from lvalue version?

Comment: @rubix_addict The rvalue version of the operator could return an rvalue reference to the contained value.

Comment: That seems quite reasonable. Do you know why rvalue versions of `operator[]` are not present in standard library?

Comment: Most likely because it would be an ABI-breaking change, and standard library vendors don't like these.

Comment: I fail to see why #1 OP mentioned is valid.  std::forward<Container>(c) returns rvalue reference to c and then we call operator[], regardless whether operator[] returns a copy of the element, or a reference to the element, it seems to me std::forward<Container>() isn't necessary at all.  Could you please clarify how overloading operator[] entails the necessity of std::forward<Container> in this case?  Thanks in advance.